# PHP script appending html tag on JSON output

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a ajax script written using jQuery calling a php script that is supposed to return a JSON string after a DB select. However, the php script is returning both the JSON string followed by a closing html tag. The page outputs nothing else (the only print command in the script is shown). I cannot find where that tag is being added. My server (running PHP5.4) is setup to prepend and append files, however I have that overridden. As a work around, I’m using exit() to abort any other output. The JSON is being built properly and I can go directly to the php script and see it just the string, but automatically wrapping it in properly html and body tags. With the exit() being called I can use the JSON properly. However, in the interest in cleaner code, I want to solve this problem for future development.

jq.info.js snippet:

```
function getCharInfo(chars_id){
$.ajax('/editor/jquery_info.php',{
    data: {'chars_id': chars_id, 'qtype':'charsInfo' },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
```

jquery_info.php snippet:

```
foreach($chobj->char as $key=>$char){
        $charInfo[$key] = parse_syn($char, 1);
    }
    $charInfo = json_encode($charInfo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    print($charInfo);
    exit;
```

The parse_syn function simply replaces html entities with UTF-8 equivalents (i.e. '&rquo;' to ’, '--' to '—' etc).
Any insight or settings to look into with PHP’s setup would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the closing html tag....just </html>?

Comment: have you tried changing the datatype to 'jsonp'

Comment: have you tried echo instead of print or simply return instead of print?

Comment: the closing tag is </html> and neither changing it to echo nor jsonp works. Thanks for the ideas though.